# Accounts RecordType Check condition on Task Workflow

Tags: workflow, tasks, workflowoutboundmessage, workflowrule

I have workflow Rule on Task
which sends outbond message when "created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria"

This happens with each and every Task - But 
I want Outbond Message to be sent only when Tasks-> Account -> RecordType='XYZ'  i.e. Task.RelatedTo RecordType should be 'XYZ'

**In short - Can we add Parent Record Type Check in Workflow Rule ?**

Notes : 
* Can not use Trigger

Answer (score 1):

The formula criteria for Workflow does not permit traversing the `Task.Account` relationship

However, the decision criteria for Process Builder does allow specification of the `Task.Account` relationship

[image]

Comment: Can we send outbond Message from Process Builder

Comment: Good point, it can't, but it can set a field update that then triggers a workflow or you could use invocable methods and do the outbound message via APEX

Comment: Ok, but this seems changing too many things. Will Creating one Field on Task (store Account.RecordTypeName) work ? or is it a bad idea ?

Comment: that will work too